# Is it possible to fix unused variable in function for jslint and jshint?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I have the following line in javascript

```
$.each(words, function (key, val) {
```

However, in jslint and jshint I keep on getting the below

```
unused variable key
```

I want to know how to fix this through coding.I read this post [JSLint message: Unused variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583623/jslint-message-unused-variables) . HOwever, I want to know if it is possible if I can fix this through coding rather than writing a comment to ignore it?

Comment: Comments are the way to go. I don't see the reason for trying to fix something that's not broken.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [JSLint message: Unused variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583623/jslint-message-unused-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "fix" it by doing something with the variable, but you don't need to. It is a warning (not an error), and one that is expected in an `each` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **for loop** if words is purely an array.

```
for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++){
```