# NodeJS unused variable

Tags: node.js, jslint

My linter is complaining that the `req` and `next` variables are not being used. I know its minor but what would be the appropriate way to fix this?

```
/* GET home page. */                                                           
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {                                     
  res.render('index', {title: 'JDA POC'});                                     
});
```

I tried to remover `req` and `next`, but that blew up. I tried changing `req` and `next` to null, but got another error.

Is there a solution or should I just ignore the JSLint?

Comment: You can definitely just get rid of `next` although I'm not sure how to fix the warning about `req` not being used

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6583623/398606)?

Comment: Get a better linter. `req` is required, if the linter warns otherwise it is incorrect. `next` can be safely removed, as it is in fact not needed.

Comment: @KevinB my linter is stating that is not being used

Comment: My linter only gives a warning on next, not req

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways around this, but the easiest is to use your "one `ignore`" like a lifeline. JSLint finally gave in to the fact that some third party libraries are going to send you more parameters than you need, as in this case, I assume, and there's no way to clean things up.

### The current solution

To make things clearer on someone reading your code, you can mark *one* parameter as the `ignore` parameter. Combined with [Kevin B's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487917/nodejs-unused-variable#comment52836780_32487917) that you can remove the last parameter, `next`, from this function, as it's unused as well, you can use this code to solve your issue:

```
/*jslint white:true */
/*global router */
router.get("/", function(ignore, res) {
  "use strict";
  res.render("index", {title: "JDA POC"});
});
```

That code works on [the newest version of JSLint](http://jslint.com). `ignore` is [something of a convention in JSLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613790/jslint-error-expected-ignore-and-instead-saw-ex/16626793#16626793), and is used in a couple of different ways.

Just to be overly clear, obviously you *can't* say `function(ignore, ignore, next)` and ignore two params, because you're "redefined `ignore`" at this point. So this solution is very limited, and doesn't work in some cases.

### The old solution

Unfortunately, that code doesn't lint [on the older version of JSLint](http://old.jslint.com), which is what some people still have to use to lint their code!

There, you're stuck with the `unparam` declaration, though I'd suggest still cleaning off `next` and using the what-will-work-soon `ignore` convention.

```
/*jslint white:true */
/*global router */
/*jslint unparam:true */
router.get('/', function(ignore, res) {
  "use strict";
  res.render('index', {title: 'JDA POC'});                                     
});
/*jslint unparam:false */
```

### The insane old solution, which is more common than you'd think

Other people have gone absolutely bat-crazy writing convoluted wrappers so this isn't an issue. I hate that, but here's an example for completeness (I think this kind of junk is why Crockford added the `ignore` param):

```
/*jslint white:true, sloppy:true */
/*global router */
function convolutedRearrangementHack(res) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'JDA POC'});
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {                                     
  convolutedRearrangementHack(res, req, next);
});
```

I mean, that lints, but it's horrible. Sometimes you can use this successfully-ish by creating your own wrappers grouped in a single, global namespace, but I don't like getting any farther from my third party libraries than I have to.

### Critique of JSLint ;^)

Personally, I'm not sure `ignore` is that much clearer than using the names the function signature expects. I'll admit this is one JSLint rule I'm not 100% convinced is as useful as its alternatives. That is, everyone knows what `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});` is, even if they only want the `errorThrown`, but only folks who understand the inner workings of JSLint understand why you might have `ignore` in your param list. I think there's value in using the well-known function signature when interfacing with third party libraries.

Seems JSLint should see when a function is being called on a declared `global` object and not complain, or at least have an option to say that certain `global` entries are objects outside of your control.

### The *post scriptum* suggestion

**EDIT:** If `router.get` is code under your control, and there's use case for using *only `req`*, consider refactoring the order of parameters so that they match use priority order. I'll give Crockford that that isn't an unuseful practice (heavy hedging, I know!).

Answer (score 1):

Tell JSLint to supress this warning. That's the best you can do.

```
/*jslint unparam: true*/

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {                                     
  res.render('index', {title: 'JDA POC'});                                     
});

/*jslint unparam: false*/
```

Another solution would be to name the variable as **ignore**.

Like:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, ignore) {                                     
  res.render('index', {title: 'JDA POC'});                                     
});
```

From [JSLint help](http://www.jslint.com/help.html):

> JSLint introduces a new reserved word: ignore. It is used in parameter
>   lists and in catch clauses to indicate a parameter that will be
>   ignored. This replaces the old unparam option. Unused warnings will
>   not be produced for ignore.
>
> function handler(ignore, value) {
>       return do_something_useful(value);
>   }

Comment: Will that do that for every variable that is declared and not used?

Comment: If you want so, remove the second instruction: `/*jslint unparam: false*/`.